# What are the benefits of learning Slovianto or Interslavic as an introduction to Slavic languages?

Tags: learning-methods, effectiveness, constructed-languages, slavic-languages

I don't plan to learn a specific Slavic language, but I want to be able to grasp the subject of any text written in any Slavic language. The constructed languages [Slovianto](http://steen.free.fr/interslavic/slovianto.html) and [Interslavic](http://steen.free.fr/interslavic/grammar.html) look interesting to me, since they use the common words of Slavic languages and simplify the grammar. The main problem is Interslavic has very few speakers and few resources.

Despite these possible shortcomings, what are the benefits of learning Slovianto or Interslavic?

Comment: It depends on how you use your time

Comment: [This question about learning Esperanto seems to be somewhat related, and might even answer your question.](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-do-experts-recommend-learning-esperanto)

Comment: There is indeed a good degree of mutual intelligibility between slavic languages, and it might be a viable approach to learn a constructed inter-slavic language. Unfortunately, I don't know about Slovianto and Interslavic, and I am not aware about studies of mutual intelligibility including such constructed languages.

Comment: As @J.Past noted, I'm fairly sure that reading through the answer on the linked question will answer this question. Voted to close as duplicate.