# Are there any studies on the propaedeutic value of international auxiliary languages other than Esperanto?

Tags: reference-request, constructed-languages

One of the reasons why experts recommend learning Esperanto is its [propaedeutic value](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/1971/800), which has been the subject of several studies. However, Esperanto is not the only [(international) auxiliary language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_auxiliary_language); other examples include [Ido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ido_(language)), [Interlingua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlingua), [Afrihili](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afrihili) and [Interslavic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interslavic_language). (Some call Interslavic a zonal constructed language, but the distinction between zonal and international is not relevant here.)

Hence my question: **Are there any studies on the propaedeutic value of international auxiliary languages other than Esperanto?**

Tip: [Resources for Researching Language Learning Questions](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/440/800).

Answer (score -1):

While I can't say for absolute definite, I think the answer is **no**.

Esperanto is by far and away the most lively and widely spoken/taught IAL and, since the others are so comparatively rare (especially Afrihili, since there is relatively little available information on the language), it seems unlikely that it would be practical to conduct such a study on any other IAL.

(If anyone does know of any evidence to contradict the above, please do let me know!)

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE. Your answer would be improved if you mentioned where you looked for the studies; maybe with Google Scholar or reading the relevant scholarly journals?